# Serve different pages with the same URL

Tags: url, nginx, server, seo

I have two HTML pages. a.html is a mobile version of my site, b.html is the desktop version. How can I set these two pages to use the same URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy and I have already implemented this. You can check out wittyfeed.com, it serves different files for mobile and desktop.

It can be done as follow,

```
http {
   ....
   map $http_user_agent $ind {
       "~*mobile" a.html;
       default b.html;
   }


   server {
       ...
       index $ind;
       ...
       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ $ind;
       }
   }
}
```

The above code runs as, it sets value for variable $ind, as a.html if the request comes from mobile or b.html otherwise. Then, accordingly it tries to fetch the file. :)

Edited w.r.t. comment below, *not tested,

```
http {
   ...
   map $http_user_agent $proxy_addr {
      "~*mobile" test-qa.firebaseapp.com/mobile;
      default  localhost:8080/test/jsp/index.jsp;
   }

   server {
      ...
      location /test {
         proxy_pass $proxy_addr;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanx for response, my two files are on different server so is it possible to achieve the same.if yes then how

Comment: yes it is possible, you can make use of proxy_pass, like,                     location / {proxy_pass server_address/$ind; }

Comment: currently i have like this
http {
    
 }
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name  dev.example.com ;
  root         /usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT;
location  /test {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
   proxy_read_timeout 900;
  }
     
}


i have an application in java which is runnung on port 8080. and i want that when user comes from desktop then the page will serve from java having port 8080 (localhost:8080/test/jsp/index.jsp) and if user comes from mobile then page will serve from this url https://test-qa.firebaseapp.com/mobile/

Comment: I'll edit my answer w.r.t. your comment, is your                                         test-qa.firebaseapp.com/mobile independently working properly? and desktop version independently working properly?

Comment: i will check it then let you know

Comment: hi it's working fine with mobile redirection but not working with desktop. showing error 502

Comment: 1- try to check whether your java application is running or not, 2- change localhost with 127.0.0.1, 3- check error log

Comment: Welcome, you might want to press that up button.  ;)

Comment: so if url have some parameter so how can i forward those parameter to proxy pass URL
example: /test?utm_source=google

Comment: for the above mentioned utm_source, it is stored in $arg_utm_source, and similarly it is stored for all, look for $arg in nginx